# Use of Keyboard Accelerator and Keyboard Access Keys in Windows 10 UWP with ContentDialog

Tags: uwp, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

When using a windows 10 UWP Content Dialog, the Page behind the dialog is 'grayed out' and the buttons and other controls do not respond to click event (Good!).  However, I have discovered that the Keyboard Accelerators (CTRL-X for example), or Keyboard Access Keys (Alt-A for example) are still active.  This can cause many problems (in my case, either re-calling the content dialog which give an error, or leaving the page while the dialog is still active).  The only fix I have found is to manually disable all the affected controls when showing the content dialog, but I was hoping someone had a better solution.

UPDATE:
Thanks for comments.  I created a new project to double check, and I also double checked my own project.  What I found is this:  My mistake on KeyboardAccelerator (i.e. CTRL-X), that does not work (as it should not).  However, I have confirmed that in my simple test project and my original, AccessKey (i.e. ALT-X) does indeed still work with the content dialog showing. See image below... Selecting ALT highlights the keys with the dialog open, and the pressing 's' or 'x' does indeed fire the button click event.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I just checked, the keyboard accelerators in the back of the a content dialog doesn't respond while content dialog is visible. Try to reproduce this issue in a new UWP app.

Comment: Hello, When `ContentDialog` is displayed, the scope of Focus will be limited to `ContentDialog`. Controls that are not within the scope of `ContentDialog` cannot get focus, so in general, Keyboard Accelerator will not work. Have you created a custom shortcut key through the `Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated` event?

Comment: One more thing... I just discovered the same issue on Windows 10 Mail.  To Replicate... Start a new email, type some things, then select Discard.  A dialog will show.  While background items are prevented from being clicked on, selecting ALT enables the menus in Mail, allowing several things to happen behind the dialog (I was able to add an attachment, for example).

Comment: Hello @Ron , when you actively set the AccessKey, the application will respond to the keyboard accelerator, which is not ContentDialog can prevent. You can try to create a global boolean variable (such as IsDialogShow) and set the variable to True when calling `ContentDialog.ShowAsync()`. Check the variable when the button is triggered and return if it is True

Comment: Thanks Richard - Seems that is not how a modal dialog should work, but indeed it does.  I have implemented something similar to what you mentioned within the View Model for the page, disabling buttons when the content dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a pretty good solution (for my use case at least).  I created a common function to call any ContentDialogs.  I pass into that function the current Page.  Before showing the dialog I set the Page.IsEnabled property to false, and then set back to true when exiting the function when the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this blog post which solved it: https://reflectionit.nl/blog/2022/accelerator-keys-for-contentdialog-buttons. It uses a attached properties which can be used in the Style of the Buttons.

```
<ContentDialog x:Class="ContentDialogDemoUWP.ConfirmContentDialog"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:helpers="using:ContentDialogDemoUWP.Helpers"
               Title="Confirm"
               CloseButtonText="Cancel"
               PrimaryButtonText="Yes"
               SecondaryButtonText="No">
    <ContentDialog.PrimaryButtonStyle>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource AccentButtonStyle}" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="helpers:KeyboardAcceleratorsServices.KeyboardAccelerators">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <helpers:KeyboardAcceleratorList>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Y" />
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="J" />
                    </helpers:KeyboardAcceleratorList>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentDialog.PrimaryButtonStyle>
    <ContentDialog.SecondaryButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="helpers:KeyboardAcceleratorsServices.KeyboardAccelerator">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="N" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentDialog.SecondaryButtonStyle>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Are you sure you want this?" />
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```